# $f(x + c_1) = f(x)$ and $g(x + c_2) = g(x).$,$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x) − g(x)) = 0.$ Then $f = g$.$

Tags: real-analysis

If $c_1, c_2 > 0,$ and if $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions (not assumed to be continuous) such
that for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$

$f(x + c_1) = f(x)$ and $g(x + c_2) = g(x).$
Further, assume that
$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x) -g(x)) =0$
Then $f = g.$

I tried to prove this in following way:

Suppose $f(a) \neq g(a)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}.$
Then $f(a+nc_1) \neq g(a+nc_2)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$\Rightarrow\quad \lim_{n \to \infty} f(a+nc_1) \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} g(a+nc_2)$

which contradicts the assumption that
$\lim_{x\to\infty}
(f(x) − g(x)) = 0.$

Is this a correct solution?

Comment: Hey :) Unfortunately, you don't know, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) $ exists. Think about a nonconstant but periodic function like Sine, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: If $\frac{c_1}{c_2}\in\mathbb Q$, you can find a constant $c>0$ s. t. $f(x) =f(x+c) $ and $g(x) =g(x+c) $ hold for all real $x$.

Comment: $f(x)=f(x-c_1)$ for all  $x$. Is it useful?